# Negation of "If n is a perfect square, then all of it's p-levels, for a prime factor, is even"

Tags: logic

I am trying to negate the statement "If $n$ is a perfect square, then all of its p-levels, for a prime factor, is even"

My guess is "If $n$ is not a perfect square, then for at least one of its p-levels, for a prime factor, is odd"

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your guess has a big problem: it's entirely possible for your statement and the original statement to both be true (because one only considers about perfect squares, and the other only considers non-squares).  If you truly negated the sentence, the two sentence should be in direct opposition.

Comment: "There do exist $n$ which are perfect squares for which at least one of it's p-levels, for a prime factor, is not even".

Answer (score 1):

"If $A$, then $B$" is logically equivalent to "not $A$, or $B$".  When negating an *or* statement, you negate both statements, and change it to an *and* statement.  So the negation of "if $A$, then $B$" is "$A$ and not $B$".

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the statement "$n$ is a perfect square" and let $Q$ be the statement "all of $n$'s $p$-levels, for a prime factor, are even".  Your first statement is $P\Rightarrow Q$.  What you've done in making your second statement is you've negated $P$ and $Q$ separately, giving you $\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$.  But what you want is $\neg(P\Rightarrow Q)$, not $\neg P\Rightarrow \neg Q$.  These are not logically equivalent (write down a truth table if you don't see why).

The only way $P\Rightarrow Q$ can be false is if $P$ is true but $Q$ is false.  So $\neg(P\Rightarrow Q)$ is logically equivalent to $P \wedge \neg Q$.  I'll leave it to you to try and write that out in words.

Comment: If $n$ is a perfect square then there exists a prime factor of $n$ with an odd exponent (and odd p-level).

Answer (score 0):

"If $P$ then $Q$" is like a **conditional promise**. It is a **true** promise as long as it is not **broken**. The only way to break a promise is to have the condition $P$ be true and yet the promised $Q$ be false.